# How to get cardinal directions for a given latitude an longitude points

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps

HI i have a list of latitude and longitude values in a table .

I am querying in the following way

```
if($direction=='NE')
    {
    //direction is NORTH EAST
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_business where Latitude > '$lat' and Longitude > '$long"; 
        }
    else if($direction=='SE')
    {
    //SOUTH EAST
        $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_business where Latitude >'$lat' and Longitude < '$long'";
    }
    else if($direction=='SW')
    {
    //SOUTH WEST

    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_business where Latitude < '$lat' and Longitude < '$long'";
    }
    else if($direction=='NW')
    {
    //NORTH WEST
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_business where Latitude < '$lat' and Longitude > '$long'";
    }
```

**$direction** will have (**SE,NE,SW,NW**) the (iphone)phone **sensor** will send the direction.
I am getting the values if only checked once. 
When ever the device is moved in other direction the values shown are outofbound. How can i solve this to achieve approximate values atleast.

please help

Comment: have you checked out http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html for calculating the bearing, then convert to N,S,E,W etc.. (Equirectangular approximation should be enough for general directions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approx direction:

```
$x = ($lon2-$lon1) * cos(($lat1+$lat2)/2);
$y = ($lat2-$lat1);

$angle=atan2($y/$x);
```

Then you need to use 315 to 360 and 0 to 45 is North, 45 to 135 is East etc..

Or narrow it down again for NW, SE, NNW, SSE etc..

Comment: I am getting angle like 1.600612598889 , -0.29816817826925 , -3.0313750624002 etc but how to determine in between which directions the place is located ?